# Дублирование записей при запросе из БД

Tags: joomla, php

здравствуйте, при запросе из БД (экспорт прайс-листа из Joomla в ексель) дублируются записи

php код такой:

```
header('Content-Type: text/x-csv; charset=utf-8');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=".date("d-m-Y")."-pricelist.xls");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");
echo '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="author" content="commis" />
<title>Прайс лист товаров</title>
</head>
<body>';
echo '<table border="1"><tr><th>№</th><th>Артикул товара</th><th>Наименование</th><th>Цена</th></tr>';

$hostname               = 'localhost';
$username               = '####';
$password               = '####';
$dbName                 = '###';

mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) OR DIE("Не могу создать соединение ");
mysql_select_db($dbName) or die(mysql_error());

// Исправтье, если у вас другая кодировка в БД
mysql_query('set names utf8');
$data = mysql_query("
SELECT * FROM jos_vm_product
LEFT JOIN jos_vm_product_category_xref  ON  jos_vm_product_category_xref.product_id = jos_vm_product.product_id
RIGHT JOIN jos_vm_category ON jos_vm_category.category_id = jos_vm_product_category_xref.category_id
RIGHT JOIN  jos_vm_product_price ON jos_vm_product_price.product_id = jos_vm_product.product_id
") or die (mysql_error());
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))
{
$product_price = substr($info['product_price'], 0, -3);
echo "<tr><td>".$info['product_id']."</td><td>".$info['product_sku']."</td><td>".$info['product_name']."</td><td>".$product_price."</td>";
}
echo "</table></body></html>";
```

результат такой:

```
№   Артикул товара
1   0000-0001
1   0000-0001
1   0000-0001
1   0000-0001
1   0000-0001
2   0000-0002 

2   0000-0002 

2   0000-0002
```

вопрос. почему дублируется и как поправить?
заранее спасибо за ответ

Comment: Гм... Я бы это выложил на Говнокод.ру....

Comment: joomla! рулит =)

Comment: @ImirofF спасибо на добром слове *сарказм*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct ...
```

Должно помочь =)

Comment: Аналогичного мнения... Более того, это ненормально, когда у вас дублируются товары и это мягко говоря...

Comment: Поддерживаю @Gorets

Answer (score 0):

Используйте алиасы и перечислите какие значения нужно получить.

```
SELECT a.product_id, b.category_id {и т.д} FROM jos_vm_product AS a
LEFT JOIN jos_vm_product_category_xref AS b  ON  b.product_id = a.product_id
RIGHT JOIN jos_vm_category AS c ON c.category_id = b.category_id
RIGHT JOIN  jos_vm_product_price AS d ON d.product_id = a.product_id
```